# background image for TD

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Using jquery to validate that there is text in a text box.  When I first start my page and leave the text box null then my background image in a TD element two cells from the text box shows a red box and after I click a button.  If I enter text then click my button then a green check icon is shown directly next to the text box.  This is all good.

However, when I remove any text in the text box click my button I don't get a red box in my TD element anymore as I did the first time that I started my page.

Thanks for any assistance.

**CSS:**

```
.Error
  {
     background-image: url('../Images/Red-Error-Box.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
  }
.Empty
  {
     background: white;
     height: 15px;
     width: 237px;
  }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function firstNameError() {
    $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').addClass('Error');
    $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').text('Please enter a first name');
    $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').show();
    $('#imgFirstName').attr('src', '../Images/Red-Error-Icon.png');
    $('#imgFirstName').show();
}

function firstNameValid() {
    $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').addClass('Empty');
    $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').text('');
    $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').show();
    $('#imgFirstName').attr('src', '../Images/Green-Check-Icon.png');
    $('#imgFirstName').show();
}

//null first name.
if (!$("#tbFirstName").val()) {
     firstNameError();
}

//not null first name.
if ($("#tbFirstName").val()) {
    firstNameValid();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="style46">
    <img id="imgFirstName" alt="" class="None">
</td>
<td id="FirstNameErrorMSG" runat="server"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these two validator functions in the global scope:

```
 //null first name.
if (!$("#tbFirstName").val()) {
       firstNameError();
}

//not null first name.
if ($("#tbFirstName").val()) {
          firstNameValid();
      }
```

Which means when you alter the textbox your not telling the jQuery to do anything. I suspect you want onBlur function:

```
$(function() {

     firstNameError(); //Check on dom ready
     firstNameValid(); //Check on dom ready

$("#tbFirstName").bind('blur','focus',function() {
    myValidator();
});

    function myValidator() {
          //null first name.
          if (!$("#tbFirstName").val()) {
               firstNameError();
          }
            else if ($("#tbFirstName").val()) {
              firstNameValid();
          }
     }
});

    function firstNameError() {
        $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').addClass('Error');
        $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').text('Please enter a first name');
        $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').show();
        $('#imgFirstName').attr('src', '../Images/Red-Error-Icon.png');
        $('#imgFirstName').show();
      }

    function firstNameValid() {
        $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').addClass('Empty');
        $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').text('');
        $('#FirstNameErrorMSG').show();
        $('#imgFirstName').attr('src', '../Images/Green-Check-Icon.png');
        $('#imgFirstName').show();
      }
```

Comment: @Nick thanks for your help but I get a Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected error.  I have placed double quotes around blur and focus but still no luck.

Comment: @Nick yes I am putting in a script block.

Comment: @Nick I ended up putting a right ) on third curly bracket.  But I now get a green check box when the page first starts.  Is there a way to keep it hidden until have text entered.

Comment: @MdeVera, I fixed that syntax error above, If you don't want validation to occur right after page load, then take out `firstNameError();` and `firstNameValid();` function calls at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two if checks that you have and add

```
$(function(){
    $("#tbFirstName").change() {
        $(this).val() ? firstNameValid() : firstNameError();
    }

    $(this).val() ? firstNameValid() : firstNameError();
})
```

Comment: Hi guys I have tried both solutions but I keep getting error looking at the syntax they seem to be correct.  The error is Micorsoft jscript runtime error: object expected.